# IllegalStateException using new Parse 1.7 Android API

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm updating Parse SDK to version 1.7 and have following crash while using method `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground()`:

```
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441): java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml: 
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441): <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):   android:exported="false">
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):   <intent-filter>
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):   </intent-filter>
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441): </receiver>
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441): (Replace "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" with your own implementation if you choose to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     at com.parse.ParsePush.checkForManifestAndThrowExceptionIfNeeded(ParsePush.java:135)
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeAsync(ParsePush.java:65)
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:79)
10-02 12:56:06.426: E/AndroidRuntime(5441):     at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:88)
```

despite the fact I have copied above code from [Parse guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing) and have all mentioned lines in ma AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just noticed that text of the crash and fragment on Parse guide page differ - it should be

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

instead of what guide says:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

(notice missing `.parse` in actions names).